# Decrypt password using bcrypt php

Tags: php, php-5.3, bcrypt

I search how to decrypt a password stored in bcrypt using php, but I don't find a good explaination. Could you please send some useful links ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: bcrypt is a hashing function so you can't "decrypt" the passwords. You can only compare them to the stored hashes, if you have any. Check out the bcrypt article on wikipedia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot decrypt a password stored with bcrypt. That's the whole point of using a cryptographic hash function.

All you can do is check if a given password matches (see [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php?rq=1)). This method could be applied repeatedly with many candidates, that is called "brute force attack", and it is not feasible for strong passwords.

Comment: *"that is called "brute force attack", and it is not feasible for strong passwords."* until we have quantum computers.